# org.eclipse.persistence.moxy;2.3.2: not found when resolving jersey-bundle 1.19.1

Tags: java, maven, ivy

I have encountered an exception when trying to `ivy:install` the `jersey-bundle 1.19.1` module into a local (file-system-based) Ivy resolver. I have managed to reproduce this using the much shorter below code.

## failing case

I define two resolvers in the `ivysettings.xml` below. One is the public `ibiblio` resolver and the other is a local (file-system-based resolver) into which I want to copy over the module (and its dependencies) from `ibiblio`:

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="public" />

    <resolvers>
        <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />

        <filesystem name="fs-local">
            <ivy
                pattern="/tmp/local-ivy-repo/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
            <artifact
                pattern="/tmp/local-ivy-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
        </filesystem>

    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Using the above `ivysettings.xml` file I then have the following Ant file to `ivy:install` the module I am interested in:

```
<project name="local repository importation" default="install-locally">

    <target name="install-locally" description="import module from public Maven repository and install into local filesystem repository" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
        <ivy:settings id="ivysettings-ibiblio-to-local" file="ivysettings.xml"/>
        <ivy:install settingsRef="ivysettings-ibiblio-to-local"
                     organisation="com.sun.jersey"
                     module="jersey-bundle"
                     revision="1.19.1"
                     from="public"
                     to="fs-local"
                     transitive="true"
                     overwrite="true"/>
    </target>    
</project>
```

When I execute (using `Ant`) the above file, I eventually get the following message:

```
 :: problems summary ::
 :::: WARNINGS
 module not found: org.eclipse.persistence#org.eclipse.persistence.moxy;2.3.2
 ==== public: tried
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.3.2/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.3.2.pom
   -- artifact org.eclipse.persistence#org.eclipse.persistence.moxy;2.3.2!org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar:
   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.3.2/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.3.2.jar
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
 :: org.eclipse.persistence#org.eclipse.persistence.moxy;2.3.2: not found
 ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

This is apparently a WARNING not an ERROR (not sure how crucial is the difference in this case). Looking in the `/tmp/local-ivy-repo/` directory I see a number of modules and jars (including `jersey-bundle`).

## successful case

If, on the other hand, I try to pull down the `jersey-bundle` dependency from the public repository (without using `ivy:install` to "install" it locally), e.g. using the following Ant file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"
         basedir="."
         default="retrieve-ivy-deps"
         name="foo">

    <target name="retrieve-ivy-deps"
            description="resolve and retrieve dependencies with ivy">
        <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml"/>
        <ivy:resolve file="ivy.xml"/>
        <ivy:retrieve conf="with-transitive"
                      pattern="ivy-jars/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
                      sync="true"
                      type="jar, bundle"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

… and the following Ivy file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="foo" module="bar"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="with-transitive"  description="IVY jars with transitive dependencies"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.sun.jersey"  name="jersey-bundle"  rev="1.19.1"  conf="with-transitive->default"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

… then, I don't see any errors or warnings, and at the end of the operation I see two files in the `ivy-jars` directory: `jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar` and `jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar`.

My questions are:

1. what is the meaning and significance of the warning message in the failing case and how do I address it?
2. why is Ant/Ivy able to pull from `ibiblio` module `jersey-bundle 1.19.1` and all its transitive dependencies without failing but is not able to `ivy:install` it? In other words, why does the successful case succeed where the failing case fail?

   3. In the successful case, in the corresponding Ivy file, I am asking for the module and all its transitive dependencies (as I am using the `default` configuration: `<dependency org="com.sun.jersey"  name="jersey-bundle"  rev="1.19.1"  conf="with-transitive->default"/>`). Yet only 2 jars are downloaded. In contrast to that when I look at the `ivy-1.19.1.xml` I see about 20 dependencies and, even in the failing case, when I look at the `/tmp/local-ivy-repo/` directory I see all of them (except the `moxy 2.3.2`). Why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a configuration on the install task as follows:

```
<ivy:install organisation="com.sun.jersey" ... conf="compile"/>
```

Always a good idea to include a configuration mapping. The error appears to be an issue retrieving a non existent optional "provided" scope dependency.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
├── ivysettings.xml
└── local-ivy-repo
    ├── com.sun.jersey
    │   └── jersey-bundle
    │       └── ivys
    │           ├── ivy-1.19.1.xml
    │           ├── ivy-1.19.1.xml.md5
    │           └── ivy-1.19.1.xml.sha1
    └── javax.ws.rs
        └── jsr311-api
            ├── ivys
            │   ├── ivy-1.1.1.xml
            │   ├── ivy-1.1.1.xml.md5
            │   └── ivy-1.1.1.xml.sha1
            └── jars
                ├── jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
                ├── jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar.md5
                └── jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar.sha1
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

  <target name="build">
    <ivy:install organisation="com.sun.jersey"
                 module="jersey-bundle"
                 revision="1.19.1"
                 from="public"
                 to="fs-local"
                 transitive="true"
                 overwrite="true"
                 conf="compile"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="public" />

  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name="public" m2compatible="true" />

    <filesystem name="fs-local">
      <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/local-ivy-repo/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
      <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/local-ivy-repo/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

Comment: If I get this right you are effectively saying that `provided` configuration of the `jersey-bundle` module (as defined in its `ivy.xml`) is wrong and the only way to go around this is to only install in the local Ivy repository the `compile` configuration of the module. I'm not an Ivy expert but I would expect a facility to exist allowing client programmers to override the dependencies declared in a module. I think this is what `overrides` is meant to do in an `ivy.xml` file but apparently it can' t be used with the `install` task. Am I missing anything?